# Is there a way to control the Service Worker in create-react-app in terms of fetching - it is caching 2000 HTTP requests after initial load

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, workbox

My App I am using Create-React-App, it works 100% and passes all PWA Lightspeed tests.

My App has 1000x Audio clips (small in size) and 1000x SVGs (small in size), however they amount to about 10MB.

I enable the service worker as I want a PWA i.e. install-able. I have tried using lazy/suspense but this only worked for loading that particular component.

It showed "still loading", as the FETCH efforts were still happening in the background. Somebody on 3G and slower connections, and older phones as I have tested, it just crashes.

Is there a way I can still have a PWA and have some control on how quickly it tries to FETCH the rest of the assets.

I had react-snap also installed to try and help, but this is as I realized not related.

The Fetch needs to be more "gentle" or something. How should I go about handling this situation?

Comment: I suspect this also prevents the "Add to Home Screen" from appearing until ALL of the assets have been loaded? As many testers said they cannot see this

Comment: There's many ways to address this issue. How about `await`ing 100 fetches at a time and recursively calling until all assets are fetched?

Comment: Thanks, I am bit novice so will research how to do that. Note, I want the add to homescreen to come up before it starts fetching everything. I suspect I have to figure that out as well.

Comment: I managed to sort this out without ejecting